# Fixed leading and trailing constraints with a center constraint may cause clipping

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, autolayout

have a label to which i have provided fixed leading and have aligned horizontal center, But the xcode is giving warning for that. what is the issue in that?

Comment: please provide some more info, error or screenshots for better understand.

Comment: You are missing vertical constraint. Adding `y position` constraint should fix it

Comment: Hi there, please read this [help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before asking. Then put some code so we can help you with your code.

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra constraint...

If you have a `Leading` constraint ***AND*** a `Trailing` constraint, there is no need for a `Horizontal Center` constraint.

Remove that center constraint and the warning should go away.

Comment: I have only given it a leading constant constraint, horizontal center constraint, top and bottom constant constraint. doesnt have a trailing constant constraint but a label beneath it has its trailing aligned with it.

Comment: *"... leading constant constraint, horizontal center constraint ..."* is an unusual way to set constraints. Remove the horizontal-center constraint, and constrain the label's trailing (same value you used for leading). That will effectively "center" the label.